# Probablistic linear regression predictions for simulation tasks

Tags: regression, distributions, simulation, boosting

I have a linear regression task where I am trying to predict in the interval of roughly [-100, 100]. I'd like to build a GBM (it doesn't have to be) that allows me to see the probability distribution of potential outcomes instead of the point prediction.

My end goal is to sample from that distribution for a simulation exercise.

If it simplifies things greatly, it would be reasonable (for my task) to assume the error structure is normal, that is, a specified mean and variance would be enough to generate a distribution I can sample from.

I explored quantile regression a bit, but it's not directly suited to the simulation task (since you need all quantiles for simulation, and would have to calculate of impute them).

Comment: Assuming normality and such you can use prediction intervals for this, otherwise bayesian models would give you this as you could sample from them.

Comment: Are you willing to assume constant variance?

Comment: I would use a probabilistic programming approach here: PyMC/Stan/TFProbability/etc. and just look at the [posterior predictive distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution). Also, bootstrap, the “poor man’s” posterior, is always an option. :) The above being said, I would challenge you to take a hold-out set, estimate your residuals there, use those residuals as your "error distribution" (mean/variance/skewness) and show that any other approach is "practically better" and not just a theoretical exercise.

Comment: (Wow, I just realised I am late here... anyway, +1.)